# Sudden high coolant temperature

Tags: coolant, temperature, skoda, octavia

After installing a new coolant regulator and burping a system sudden high temperature occures.
 [Following picture show 95 degree at 92 degree of oil temperature but coolant temperature can reach even 120 degree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SHMA.jpg)

Sudden rising occure mostly only ones when engine has resently been warmed-up. After the first pick temperature become steady for the rest of the driving. I add even a youtube link from one of my rides: https://youtu.be/vtE0mGhGznE

Comment: The temperature increase is likely to be the thermostat opening and letting hot coolant through - and as the coolant system is pressurised the temperature will be above 100 deg c...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you please tell us what the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question is (if it's evident in the image or video, I can't see it here at work)? Knowing this info will help us to know if this is a common issue on the vehicle or if there might be some other known issue involved.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 2014/octavia/2.0 tdi

Comment: Get only Fault code 100103 and lukewarm coolant in expansion tank.